# psycopg2 folder zipped into python venv lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, psycopg2

I am trying to add the packages for psycopg2 into my zipped folder for my python lambda function.  I am using Python version 3.8. Here is the psycopg2 documentation [psycopg2](https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2).

From these docs it seems like I have to pull the folder for psycopg2-3.8 into the zipped file for my lambda function.  However, I cannot seem to get this to successfully run.

I am using a virtual environment and creating the zip file according to these AWS docs [for virtual environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html)

To get the psycopg folder zipped I am running `zip -g my-deployment-package.zip psycopg2`

The error I am receiving is

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'test': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Any help troubleshooting this would be great.

Comment: Have you considered using layer with `psycopg2-binary`? Its much easier to setup as you don't have to compile and worry about c level dependencies.

Comment: I haven't seen that before. How is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[psycopg2-binary](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html) is a binary pip package of `psycopg2` which comes with all dependencies and does not require compiling. To use it in your lambda function, you can create a  [lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) using **docker** as described in the [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/).

Thus you can add `psycopg2-binary` to your function as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
psycopg2-binary
```

3. Run the following docker command:

The command will create layer for python3.8:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Archive the layer as zip:

```
zip -9 -r mylayer.zip python
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtime` to `python3.8`.
6. Add the the layer created in step 5 to your function.
7. I tested the layer using your code:

```
import psycopg2

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(dir(psycopg2))
    
    return "ok"
```

It  works **correctly**:

```
['BINARY', 'Binary', 'DATETIME', 'DataError', 'DatabaseError', 'Date', 'DateFromTicks', 'Error', 'IntegrityError', 'InterfaceError', 'InternalError', 'NUMBER', 'NotSupportedError', 'OperationalError', 'ProgrammingError', 'ROWID', 'STRING', 'Time', 'TimeFromTicks', 'Timestamp', 'TimestampFromTicks', 'Warning', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__libpq_version__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_connect', '_ext', '_json', '_psycopg', '_range', 'apilevel', 'compat', 'connect', 'errors', 'extensions', 'paramstyle', 'threadsafety', 'tz']
```

p.s.

The steps were execution on linux. If you don't have one you can create a linux ec2 instance and setup docker there if you are not sure how to modify the commands for Windows or Mac.

Comment: Will i I need to pip install docker in my project for this to work?

Comment: @tdammon Installation of docker depends on your operating system. If you are not sure how to do it, its maybe good time to learn. The use of docker to create lambda layers  is the most reliable way of adding  various dependencies to your function. So once you learn how to do it once, creating layers for 90% of other possible python packages will be straightforward in your future projects.

Comment: I'm working on learning the process.  I'm running into some issues on step 4.  I am getting an error saying `zip warning: name not matched: python`. I'm not sure if this is becuase I am on a Mac or not.

Comment: I think I figured out the error I listed above.  My `lib` folder is inside a `venv` folder.  Even when I update that I get an error saying ` It looks like a path. File 'echo psycopg2-binary > ./requirements.txt' does not exist.`. It seems to me this indicates my file structure has an error.  Where in my project directory should I be making the mylayer folder?

Comment: @tdammon The layer is fully separate from your project. You can create `mylayer` anywhare you want. Its not part of your project.

Comment: thank you.  And where are you running command #3 from.  I am trying to run it from the mylayer folder and I get the error `File 'echo psycopg2-binary > ./requirements.txt' does not exist.`

Comment: @tdammon every command is run in `mylayer` folder. You can create `requirements.txt` manually in any text editor. It content is only one line: `psycopg2-binary`. I modified the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally I have this running.

Comment: @tdammon Glad it worked out. So now creating majority of future layers with pyton dependencies is just basically updating the `requirements.txt`.

Comment: yes I think I understand the process now.  Is it best practice to do this with all dependencies or is including a dependency package still recommended for other dependecies?

Comment: @tdammon Layers are better as you can re-use the layer across multiple lambda functions. So the layer you build for pg, you can use for many functions, without needing to worry how to bundle it with your actual project.

Answer (score 0):

AWS lambda layer can also be created without spinning out the docker.

1. Download the required wheel file from here based on the python version: https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/#files
   For example: Psycopg2 version 2.9.9 compatible with Python 3.11 and x86 64 bit arc.
   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/85/62825cabc6aad53104b7b6d12eb2ad74737d268630032d07b74d4444cb72/psycopg2_binary-2.9.9-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
2. Extract the `whl` file using zip application.
3. Rename the extracted folder as `Python`
4. Compress the file using zip command
   `zip -9 -r layer_name.zip python`

Hope this helps in generating the lays quickly.